# Unable to extend the root volume /dev/root of a Yocto build VM

Tags: linux

I have created an emulator yocto build VM. The *.vmdk file provided create an space of around 273MB. Its too small, when new terminal is opened its root memory gets full. 
I can mount a drive but but it remians as external hdd.

Result of `df -h`

```
Filesystem  size    used    available   use%    mounted on
/dev/root   273.5M  273.5M    0M        100%    /
devtmpfs    500.0M  0         500.0M    0%      /dev
tmpfs       500.3M  0         500.3M    0%      /dev/shm
tmpfs       500.3M  9.4M      490.9M    2%      /run
tmpfs       500.3M  0         500.3M    0%      sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs       500.3M  9.4M      490.9M    2%      /etc/machine-id
tmpfs       500.3M  16.0K     500.3M    0%      /tmp
```

Even I tried to change the ROOTFS and increase the size of root directory but it failed to increase.